# jquery load does not work in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to load json file when I click on one of the buttons and I want to do that by using **load** method in **jquery**.
problem is when I write that code

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")
buttons.forEach(function(butt, index) {
  butt.addEventListener("click", dos)

  function dos() {
    $("body").load("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>


<button>Change color</button>
<button>Change color</button>
<button>Change color</button>
<button>Change color</button>
```

console give me that error

> main.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function
>       at HTMLImageElement.dos

but when I delete all javascript except

```
$("body").load("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
```

it works

**NOTE**: I don't know why the code work here - on stack overflow editor- and on[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: The code works here because by default snippets run *after* the DOM has fully loaded. In your own page you need to manually ensure this has happened, like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: You're also better off placing `dos` outside of your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works here because, by default, SO snippets and jsFiddles run *after* the DOM has fully loaded. In your own page you need to manually ensure this has happened by listening for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event on the `window`. You should also define the `dos()` function outside of the loop.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")
  buttons.forEach(function(butt, index) {
    butt.addEventListener("click", dos)
  });
});

function dos() {
  $("body").load("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
}
```

If you'd prefer to use jQuery for the entire thing it would look like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('buton').on('click', () => $("body").load("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"));
});
```

Comment: I understand you but It is still give the same error.
even after I put all the code inside the DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: Are you using jquery.js, or jquery.slim.js?

Comment: I use jquery.js, that link  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js

Comment: you can write the code on your code editor to make sure

Comment: I have. The code above works absolutely fine. I'd suggest you do some debugging and check the console for errors.